# Interview Phase 2, I admit that I was bad in Phase 1, they cancel the interview

Tags: interviewing, self-confidence

It happened on a recent interview to me.

This case was the following:

1. Interview #1. They ask very deeply from a field which I know not very deeply (but worked already some years with it). My answers are clearly superficial or in a case, I can not even answer them.
2. Despite that, I still get the opportunity to continue the recruiting with Interview#2. This happens on a second phone interview.
3. During this interview, they are talking about, where could I do work on the best, which areas should I prepare for the interview #3, and so on. Everything points to that my low quality in the first phase was not a problem for them.
4. This surprises me, and I am ready to pass. I am thankful that I could continue the recruiting process, despite that I was probably not very good in #1.
5. After that, they quickly (but very politely) cancel the interview. They say, I was not enough convincing in the first phase #1.

Honestly, I fully agree that I was probably not the best option for the job.

But why did I get then the opportunity for #2? And why was it canceled after I admitted that I was not very good in step#1?

The employer had been a close customer of a big finance company in Germany.

What was their most likely reason to do that, and what was my mistake?

**What I am asking for, what can I learn from this?**

Comment: Only the people who interviewed you can tell you this.

Comment: @PhilipKendall Ok, but maybe there is some workplace ethics thing. The closest what I tought about, that I (undeliberately and indirectly) called in question their authority to choose, who can continue the recruitment and who can not.

Comment: @PhilipKendall Note, the formulation is: "*What was their most likely reason*", and *"What was my mistake"*. So what I am asking for, is not an insight into their mind. This would be obviously a not answerable question. What I am asking for, what can I learn from this.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere Your insights are phenomenal, you know? Now if I put everything together, I also think that this is the most likely explanation. Sad that you can not get rep for comment ups.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere So it was just coincidence and they already wanted to reject. The likely reason, why I got the second opportunity is in the answer (internal miscommunication, a better candidate appeared after I was already called in or anything).

Comment: Saying you felt not good about #1 tells them not so much about your #1 performance rather than that you do not have self-confidence, independently of whether or not they thought you did well in #1. It suggests to them you probably won't become better in #1, too, if they need you to. If you really wanted the job or at least the option of an offer, apologizing for an - in your opinion - unsatisfactory performance was not a good move. After an offer you still can turn them down if you decide it is not for you.

Comment: Moving forward, the best thing to do is to practice more to improve your knowledge and skills in order to do well in future interviews. Different companies have different criteria to reject and hire candidates at different points in their business cycles. Focus on future interviews with other companies. Good luck.

Answer (score 5):

> But why did I get then the opportunity for #2? And why was it canceled after I admitted that I was not very good in step#1?

Could be all kind of things: internal miscommunication, shift in priorities, a better candidate showed up, etc.

Why does it matter? You didn't do well in the first interview, they decided to move and so should you. Focus on what's ahead of you: the past is only meaningful if  you want to learn from it.

Best you can do at this point is think about what (if any) you could have done differently. Did you overrepresent this specific skill on your resume ? Did you miss that it was apparently critical to the role? Could you have prepared better? Did you apply to the wrong job in the first place? Could there have been a better strategy to deal with the questions you had trouble with?

None of these may be the case, but critically assessing your performance is the best you can get out of this situation

Comment: Thanks, exactly this is what I tried to do. I admitted my mistake and I was thankful for the grace. I think it was good idea. Turned out it was not. Why?

Comment: I was bad in step#1. The question is, why was it not a problem *until I admitted it*?

Comment: Maybe... admitting the problem constrained them to recognize it?

Answer (score 4):

It sounds to me from this reading that *neither one of you* thought you were a very good fit.  Therefore, just move on to something more suitable.

Hell, I once terminated an interview *myself.*  I very politely told them that based on what I'd heard so far I did not feel that this was the right role for me.  The interviewer seemed surprised ... or was he relieved?  Not every job is right for everybody, and you should *never* wind up stuck in a job that's "a pair of shoes four sizes too small," merely because you felt you had to have "a job, any job."  Being employed is not quite like being married, but it's close.  If the warning-bells are going off for any reason, listen to them. What the comic-book artists called, "spidey sense."

Comment: Well, I was clearly not a good fit, but honestly I could have done it. The questions what they've asked in step#1, were clearly much more hard than it was required for the job. And yes, I could have done it very happily, although it had been probably not very enjoyable - finance companies are typically above average in $.

Comment: My warning bells ringed because I've already some experience by companies about $ and my impression is that my cultural fit is not very good there. In the unlikely case that they employ me, likely this had been the problem and not the lack of my technical skills.

Answer (score 2):

IMHO, you should not feel stopped by impostor syndrome.

Most of positions I applied for had a lot of over-qualification in description.

Answer (score 2):

**What was their most likely reason to do that, and what was my mistake?**

As others have said, only they know why they did this. So here is a possible reason that you could learn something from. If the reason why is internal miscommunication or they change their mind, etc. then there’s really not much you can learn from that other than “welcome to bureaucracy“.

It is possible that well you had problems in interview number one, they otherwise thought that you had some good qualities, so they thought well let’s see how he does in the next phase. So when you got to the next phase, and did not “blow their socks off” they decided that there was really no need to go further. For example, you were starting off a little bit behind, and in the part of interview number two that you had you did not recover enough.

**What I am asking for, what can I learn from this?**

If you ever have a circumstance where you do poorly in an interview, especially if it is in one specific area, but you somehow move on to the next round anyway, then be prepared to discuss the deficiencies from interview 1. Not excuses, but explain that given time to think, you realize this was an area that you could improve in, and explain to them specifically what steps you have taken to improve, or to mitigate any problems that would be caused by your deficiency in knowledge or skill. It is possible they were looking to see if you had that sort of thoughtfulness, or you could redeem yourself, where are you could reassure them that the poor performance did not fully show your strengths, etc. Again, it is possible that they were looking to see if you could redeem yourself from the first interview, and after discussion they decided that you had not.